# Where has the close vote function gone?

Tags: discussion

I'm no longer seeing the option to vote to close a question since the site opened to the public, has the rep needed for this increased now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to the FAQ, it appears so. It makes sense since the site is now [open to the public](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-first-public-beta/).

Comment: Hah, yes I should've checked the FAQ. Quite a way to go to get the 3000 rep needed to vote to close

Comment: Of course now no one (except the few moderators, aka Stack Overflow employees) can close a question.

Answer (score 3):

I agree. We have relaxed the reputation requirements for the duration of the public beta.

See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq for the current rep values.